# Hex editing app data (e.g. game data)

Tags: editing

My question is I am trying to do some hex editing for an Android game that I play (increasing the amount of coins/cash in my inventory), but I'm not sure exactly which file to open up.

I will attach a screenshot of what I get when I open a file with my hex editor (the program I use is Hex Editor Free).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apps on Android are running inside a "sandbox" where they can do what they want but not affect other apps.

This means any app including your hex editor app is unable to modify other apps. Also the files you see in the path `/storage/emulated/0` (also known as `/sdcard`) are only the "public" files of the app. The bigger part is usually stored in the app-private directory where only the app itself has access to (on a non-rooted device).

If the game developer was not complete idiot editing any file you can see in your hex editor has no effect on your in-game state.